# PeerJS Set your own PeerID

Tags: javascript, peerjs

I am trying out [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/) and it works great.

Just looking at the demo's the Peer ID is auto created for you.

Is there a way to define / set your own Peer Id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide a peer id when you create the peer object:

```
var peer = new Peer('pick-an-id', {key: 'myapikey'}); 
// You can pick your own id or omit the id if you want to get a random one from the server.
```

This is right off the page you linked to under *Create a peer*.

Comment: Hi..can u plz tell me how to create a destination peerid so the caller can enter it and call??

Comment: Seems like the example @dan-d mentions is taken from https://github.com/NickCis/simple-peerjs which is not the same as PeerJS mentioned in the question.